# Generalizing the Lambert W function

Tags: lambert-w, transcendental-equations

Can an equation of the form

$ y=e^{\frac{p(y)}{q(y)}}$

be solved for $y$ in terms of the Lambert W function?

$p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials, for example

$y=e^{\frac{b(y+1)}{y^2+y+\kappa}}.$

Comment: From $y=e^{\frac{p(y)}{q(y)}}$ you get $p(y) y^{q(y)}=p(y)e^{p(y)}$. Now use $p^{-1}$ (the inverse of $p$, which might not be unique) to transform $y = p^{-1}(z)$ which gives 
$z \cdot (p^{-1}(z))^{q(p^{-1}(z))}=z e^{z}$. 
With this, you can say 
$
z = W{\Large(} z \cdot (p^{-1}(z))^{q(p^{-1}(z))} \Large)
$
But this doesn't really help, does it?

Comment: @Andreas, thanks. I'll look it up with my functions. so far I've tried many different transformations and expansions to obtain a familiar form and none of them worked out.